# C# close stream and delete file if something failed

Tags: c#, filestream

I'm working with a file stream in C#. It's a storage cache, so if something goes bad writing the file (corrupted data, ...), I need to **delete the file** and **rethrow the exception** to report the problem. I'm thinking on how to implement it in the best way. My first attempt was:

```
Stream fileStream = null;
try
{
    fileStream = new FileStream(GetStorageFile(),
        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
    //write the file ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Close the stream first
    if (fileStream != null)
    {
      fileStream.Close();
    }
    //Delete the file
    File.Delete(GetStorageFile());
    //Re-throw exception
    throw;
}
finally
{
    //Close stream for the normal case
    if (fileStream != null)
    {
      fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

As you will see, if something goes bad writing the file, the fileStream will be closed twice. I know that it works, but I don't think that is the best implementation.

I think that I could remove the `finally` block, and close the stream in the `try` block, but I have posted this here because you guys are experts and I want to hear the voice of an expert.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you put the fileStream in a using block you don't need to worry about closing it, and then just leave the cleaning up (deleting of the file in the catch block.

```
try 
{ 
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(GetStorageFile(), 
        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
    {
        //write the file ... 
    }
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    File.Delete(GetStorageFile()); 
    //Re-throw exception 
    throw; 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I believe what you want is this:

```
var fs = new FileStream(result.FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
```

I've used it with ASP.Net to have the web server return a result to a temp file that's on disk, but to make sure it's cleaned up **after** the web server **finishes** serving it to the client.

```
public static IActionResult TempFile(string tempPath, string mimeType, string fileDownloadName)
        {
            var fs = new FileStream(tempPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
            var actionResult = new FileStreamResult(fileStream: fs, contentType: mimeType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName
            };

            return actionResult;
        }
```